# Is this classed as a composite primary key?

Tags: sql

I am making a car rental system. I have a table with the information about cars and in the table I have 2 attributes one called VIN(which is a unique identification number) and I also have ULP(Unique License Plate), because they are both unique and you cannot have two primary keys in one table, will they both be classed together as Composite Primary Keys

Comment: There's nothing wrong about having multiple keys in a table. In your case you have two "non-composite" keys.

Comment: Is there a way of labelling non-composite Primary Keys

Comment: Because it is car rental and it is assumed the car will be staying for at least a year with the car rental establishment, the license plate could count as unique identifier, for which the VIN number is unique to its lifetime.  If you were creating a data table for a car sales / perhaps a mechanic shop place, then the license plate is not unique to the car, because it can change hands.  As others said too, your VIN # is the primary key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.   More likely one will be the primary key and the other will be an alternate key.

A composite key is when the combination of two columns make the row unique.  In your case you have two unique columns, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key has three attributes:

- It is never `NULL`.
- It is unique.
- There is only one per table.

Other keys (or combinations of keys) with these attributes are *candidate primary keys*.  You can choose any of them that you want for the primary key of the table.  Or, you can create a synthetic primary key yourself.

A *composite* primary key is when the primary key has more than one key.  You *could* create a composite key from your two fields, but that does not seem necessary.

Instead, you have two *candidate primary keys* and you can choose either of them as the primary key for your table.  Or declare the columns as `NULL` and unique and have an auto-incremented key.